# Multiple outbound IPs on a single GCE instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I need multiple outbound IP addresses for my Compute Engine VM to choose from for outgoing requests.
Is there an easier way then creating multiple networks and NICs?

I thought about Cloud NAT, but with multiple IPs assigned to the NAT, it always selects the same IP for every outgoing request. I need a way to select which IP is used for each request. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes you can add several NIC. But you need multiple CPU, there is limitation on the number of available NIC according with the number of CPU

Comment: 1/2) You will need to provide more details on what you are trying to accomplish and with what tools/software. If you are writing your own software, you can select which network interface to `bind` to. If you are using other software, check to see what configuration options are available. Otherwise the OS will pick the network interface to send packets to.

Comment: 2/2) Google Compute Engine VMs do not have public IP addresses. This is an important concept to understand. Instead an external public IP address is assigned to a 1-to-1 NAT which is connected to the VM's private IP address. Therefore, you need a network interface per external public IP address.